# Codewars Tiny Three-Pass Compiler JS heap out of memory

Tags: javascript

**I was doing the** [Tiny Three-Pass Compiler](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5265b0885fda8eac5900093b) **on codewars and I keep getting a error on node v.10 saying** `

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap
> out of memory Aborted (core dumped)  <--- Last few GCs --->
>
> [19:0x5578df6e1f80]     6093 ms: Mark-sweep 580.2 (592.5) -> 580.2
> (584.5) MB, 1501.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.282, current mu = 0.000)
> last resort GC in old space requested [19:0x5578df6e1f80]     6285 ms:
> Mark-sweep 580.2 (584.5) -> 580.2 (584.5) MB, 191.9 / 0.0 ms  (average
> mu = 0.243, current mu = 0.000) last resort GC in old space requested
>
> <--- JS stacktrace --->
>
> ==== JS stack trace =========================================
>
> ```
> 0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x3dbb90e5be1d] Security context: 0x3dd3dcdf3419 <JSObject>
> 1: /* anonymous */ [0x3dd3dcdcb241] [/home/codewarrior/node/test.js:~48]
> ```
>
> [pc=0x3dbb90efc9ce](this=0x3d354a868c89 ,program=0x1344e3ade909 <String[47]: [ x y z ] ( 2*3*x
>
> - 5*y - 3*z ) / (1 + 3 + 2*2)>)
>   2: /* anonymous */ [0x3d354a8463c9] [/home/codewarrior/node/test.js:214] [bytecode=0x3dd3dcdce859
>   offset=90](this=0x3d354...`

**and on node v.8 I get this error:**
`

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
> Aborted (core dumped)
> `

**The code that I am currently using is:**

```js
function isNumber (token){
  return !isNaN(token);
}
function isOperator(token){
  return "*/+-".indexOf(token) !== -1;
}

function Compiler () {};

Compiler.prototype.compile = function (program) {
  return this.pass3(this.pass2(this.pass1(program)));
};

Compiler.prototype.tokenize = function (program) {
  // Turn a program string into an array of tokens.  Each token
  // is either '[', ']', '(', ')', '+', '-', '*', '/', a variable
  // name or a number (as a string)
  var regex = /\s*([-+*/\(\)\[\]]|[A-Za-z]+|[0-9]+)\s*/g;
  return program.replace(regex, ":$1").substring(1).split(':').map( function (tok) {
    return isNaN(tok) ? tok : tok|0;
  });
};

Compiler.prototype.pass1 = function (program) {
  var tokens = this.tokenize(program);
  
  function getNextToken(){
    token = tokens.shift();
  }
  function precedenceIsNotGreater(o1, o2){
    var precedences = {
      '/' : 4,
      '*' : 3,
      '+' : 2,
      '-' : 1,
    }
    return precedences[o1] <= precedences[o2];
  }
  
  var token ;
  var outputQueue = [];
  var operatorStack = [];
  var args = [];
  
  do{
    getNextToken()
    if(token === '['){
      for(getNextToken(); token !== ']'; getNextToken()){
        args.push(token);
      }
    }else if(isNumber(token) || args.includes(token)){
      outputQueue.push(token);
    }else if(isOperator(token)){
      var o1 = token;
      for(var o2 = operatorStack[operatorStack.length-1]; operatorStack.length && isOperator(o2) && precedenceIsNotGreater(o1, o2); o2 = operatorStack[operatorStack.length -1]){
        outputQueue.push(token);
      }
      operatorStack.push(o1);
    }else if(token === '('){
      operatorStack.push(token);
    } else if(token === ')'){
      for(var nextOperator = operatorStack[operatorStack.length -1]; operatorStack.length && nextOperator !== '('; nextOperator = operatorStack[operatorStack.length-1]){
        outputQueue.push(operatorStack.pop())
      }
      operatorStack.pop()
    }
  } while(tokens.length);
  
  while(operatorStack.length){
    outputQueue.push(operatorStack.pop())
  }
  
  var output;
  
  function getNextOutput(){
    output = outputQueue.pop();
  }
  
  function buildAst(outputQueue) {
    getNextOutput();
    var node = {};
    
    if(isNumber(output)){
      node.op = 'imm';
      node.n = output;
    } else if(args.includes(output)){
      node.op = 'arg';
      node.n = args.indexOf(output);
    } else if(isOperator(output)){
      node.op = output;
      var b = buildAst(outputQueue);
      var a = buildAst(outputQueue);
      node.a = a;
      node.b = b;
    }
    return node;
  }
  return buildAst(outputQueue);
};

Compiler.prototype.pass2 = function (ast) {
  function reduceTree(ast) {
    if(ast.op === 'imm' || ast.op === 'arg') {
      return ast;
    }
    ast.a = reduceTree(ast.a);
    ast.b = reduceTree(ast.b);
    
    if(ast.a.op === 'imm' && ast.b.op === 'imm'){
     var n = Function("return " + ''+ast.a.n+ast.op+ast.b.n)();
      return{ op: 'imm', n: n}
    }
    return ast;
  }
  return reduceTree(ast)
};

Compiler.prototype.pass3 = function (ast) {
  var operatorMap = {
    '+' : 'AD',
    '-' : 'SU',
    '*' : 'MU',
    '/' : 'DI',
  }
  
  var operationDepths = {};
  var maxDepth = -Infinity;
  
  function markDepth (ast, depth = 0){
    if(ast.a && ast.b){
      maxDepth = Math.max(maxDepth, depth);
      if(!operationDepths[depth]){
        operationDepths[depth] = [];
      }
      operationDepths[depth].push(ast);
      markDepth(ast.a, depth+1);
      markDepth(ast.b, depth+1);
    }
  }
  markDepth(ast);
  var asm = [];
  
  var currentDepth = maxDepth;
  while(currentDepth >= 0){
    currentDepthOperations = operationDepths[currentDepth];
    while(currentDepthOperations.length){
     var currentOperation = currentDepthOperations.shift();
      
      if(currentOperation.b.op === 'imm'){
        asm.push('IM ' + currentOperation.b.n);
      }else if(currentOperation.b.op === 'arg'){
        asm.push('AR ' + currentOperation.b.n)
      }else{
        asm.push('PO')
      }
      
      asm.push('SW')
      
      if(currentOperation.a.aop === 'imm'){
        asm.push('IM ' + currentOperation.a.n)
      }else if(currentOperation.a.op === 'arg') {
        asm.push('AR ' + currentOperation.a.n)
      }else{
        asm.push('PO')
      }
      
      asm.push(operatorMap[currentOperation.op]);
      
      asm.push('PU')
    }
    currentDepth--;
  }
  return asm;
};
```

If anyone can help that would be great!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're posting a lot of code. This is probably an issue with recursion (heap out of memory usually means stackoverflow). Besides that, please don't use eval; it's avoidable and there are far better and more efficient, safer, solutions.

Comment: I just changed it to Function("return " + ''+ast.a.n+ast.op+ast.b.n)() and I still get the same error

Comment: Also the issue is in codewars console and not in stack overflow when i run the code and the tests through vscode I get no error

Comment: StackOverflow is an error caused by recursion. I mean not to run arbitrary code, so the function constructor doesn't do anything. Well, it looks like your issue was the infinite loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the heap overflow is that you have an infinite loop here:

```
      for(var o2 = operatorStack[operatorStack.length-1]; operatorStack.length && isOperator(o2) && precedenceIsNotGreater(o1, o2); o2 = operatorStack[operatorStack.length -1]){
        if (count-- < 0) throw "too many iterations second for";
        outputQueue.push(token);
      }
```

If this loop enters with its loop condition being true, then that loop condition will always remain true. This is because it does not pop anything from that stack. Eventually the ever growing `outputQueue` will take up all available heap memory.

The correction is to replace this:

```
    outputQueue.push(token);
```

with:

```
    outputQueue.push(operatorStack.pop());
```

Disclaimer: I didn't check for any other problems in this rather large code block. This only addresses the error you got and its cause.